# Trouble parsing csv file - can't read it 2 times

Tags: python

Super noob here, so this might be a little embarrasing.
I need to work with a csv file, and found that you can use csv.DictReader to make a list of ordered dicts. So far so good.
I can loop through the list and do stuff, but only one time.
If I want to print the dicts 2 times, it doesn´t work.

```
import csv
csv_file = open('untitled2.csv', mode='r')
csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file, delimiter = ";")

    for rows in csv_reader:
        print (rows)

    for rows in csv_reader:
        print (rows)
```

This only prints the list of dicts 1 time. I need to go through the list a number of times. but I´m not able to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to the begining of the file again : 
`csv_file.seek(0)` after the first `for`.

Don't forget to close it when you're done.
The best way to do it is in a context :

```
with open('untitiled2.csv', mode='r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file, delimiter=';')
    # your for
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked.

Comment: nice :). Don't forget to accept the answer if it solved your problem.